# Working of Affinity collocation in Apache Ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

If I have following 3 tables(here numeric values are integer values) and in table_1_key I have affinity collocation on companyId. Then how will affinity collocation happen? will table 1 entries collocate with table 2 entries or table 3 entries(as both tables have columns with integer values ranging from 1 to 10)?

```
table_1_key --> {male_personId(1-10 numeric value), companyId(1-10 numeric value), age, address} has 100 entries    
table_2_key --> {female_personId(1-10 numeric value), surname, age, address} has 20 entries
table_3_key --> {company_name, companyId(1-10 numeric value)} has 10 entries
```

In other case if let us say female_personId range changes from 1-10 to 1-5 then how will affinity collocation happen?(in other words does Apache Ignite also considers key ranges while affinity collocation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity collocation happens in the way you configure it and by default there is no collocation. Refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocate-data-with-data

According to your schema, you will most likely collocate by companyId. This means that all persons that belong to a company, will be stored on the same node together with the company object itself.

Key ranges are not affecting affinity in any way. Key is mapped to a node based on the affinity key, regardless of whether it's actually in the cache or not.

Comment: But here both companyId and female_personId objects are of integer type, so how ignite determines it has to collocate table 1 with table 3 and not with table 2. Does it determines this by looking at field names(here companyId) in table keys?

Comment: Ignite defines a node where the entry is stored in several mapping steps: cache key -> affinity key -> partition number -> node(s). The first step is controlled by the user (see the documentation). All cache keys that are mapped to the same affinity key, will be stored on the same node. And this doesn't depend on the types of cache keys, they can be different or the same.